# Mirror Web Server

Tags: web-server, cache

I am looking to set up something like this:

```
[internet]----[static mirror]----[dynamic back-end]
```

In this case, the publicly available web server is running a static cache of a web-site. The static cache may be updated periodically with content from a dynamic back end. I am thinking of both performance and security in mind.

It may not be suitable for a reverse caching proxy like *varnish* because if the back-end goes does for prolonged periods, varnish will also cache the error. However, this may be cause by my lack of understanding for the tool.

The closest that I can think of is to use *httrack* to mirror the content periodically and then to serve that content using any normal web server including *proxytrack*.

I was wondering if anyone knows the right tools to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish is the correct tool for this -- it won't cache errors unless you configure it to do so.  You might want to look into why your backend webserver is so unreliable, though.

Answer (score 1):

Squid is the other option for this, it also won't cache errors (or redirects) and can be set to "offline mode" so it won't try and refresh.

Just using `rsync` isn't too bad.